# VS Single license Multiple versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio Professional license. When I bought it I then downgraded it to 2005 Pro. Now I have a need for VS 2015 professional as well.
Is it possible to install it, side-by-side with 2005? I googled it and it says one can have multiple versions of VS side-by-side, but nowhere it says whether to buy additional license or the same will suffice.
Thanks.

Comment: You can install them side-by-side but you will need a license for all different versions.

Comment: OK so you mean VS licenses are assigned per user per version? What if I want to install VS 2015 on a different machine? Will I need another license there as well?

Comment: In any case, you need a Visual Studio 2015 license. You can not activate a 2015 version with a 2005 license.